# Переменная в AJAX

Tags: ajax, php, переменные, mysql

Здравствуйте. Мне надо вставить переменную в URL.

Вот такой скрипт:

```
<script>
function testa(el) {
    var alink = $(el).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'test.php',
      data: alink,
      success: function(data) {
         $("#refotv").text(data);
      },
    })

}
</script>
```

И мне надо сделать  что-то типа такого:

AJAX

```
var id = $(el).text('#div');
url: 'test.php?id='+id,
```

html

```
$vv = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");
while ($v = mysql_fetch_array($vv)) {
echo "<div id='refotv'>";
echo "<a onClick='testa(this);'>".$v[text]."</a><br />";
echo "<div id='div'>".$v[id]."</div><br />";
echo "</div>";

}
```

Выводит 5 строк:

```
Текст 1
1
Текст 2 
2
Текст 3
3
Текст 4 
4
Текст 5
5
```

Надо, чтобы при нажатии на текст обрабатывал именно ту строку, которую выбрал и отправлял через `var id = ...`, и выдавал ответ в #refotv именно в той строке, в которой было нажато.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Внутри цикла уберите `div id='div', div id="refotv"`, вместо них пропишите классы, типа:

```
div class="div", div class="revotf" ,или даже аттрибуты data-[]
2)<div class='refotv'>
<a onClick='testa(this);'>".$v[text]."</a><br />
<div class='div'>".$v[id]."</div><br />
</div>
..............
function testa(el){
   $link = $(el);
   $id = $link.closest('.refotv').find('.div');
   $.post('url.php',$id,function(res){
       $link.closest('.refotv').html(res);
    });

}
```

Comment: А как в url.php выводить `class='div'`